# Flex - How do I use a variable to define the name of an instantiated object

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, dynamic, object, custom-component

Essentially this is what I want to accomplish, however it doesn't work like this. Is there any solution: - The problem is I can't dynamically name a new object... ??? pulling my hair out.

```
import views.printingView;

public function initComponent(o:Array):void{
    SomeObject::Array = o;

    for(i=0; i <=SomeObject.length-1; i++){
    'invoice'+{SomeObject[i].namedID}:printingView = new printingView();
    someDisplayContainer.addChild('invoice'+{SomeObject[i].namedID});
    'invoice'+{SomeObject.namedID}.publicInitFunction(SomeObject[i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: p.s. the brackets around the SomeObject[i].namedID probably shouldn't be there, but I've tried with and without.

Answer (score 2):

From the code you posted, there's no need for a dynamically named variable at all.  The same code can be simplified to this:

```
import views.printingView;

public function initComponent(o:Array):void{
    for each(var item:Object in o)
    {
        var v:printingView = new printingView();
        someDisplayContainer.addChild(v);
        v.publicInitFunction(item);
    }
}
```

If for some reason you really need a dynamically named *variable*, you can do it like this.  This assumes the current object is declared dynamic.

```
import views.printingView;

public function initComponent(o:Array):void{
    SomeObject::Array = o;

    for each(var item:Object in o)
    {
        var name:String = 'invoice' + item.namedID;
        this[name] = new printingView();
        someDisplayContainer.addChild(this[name]);
        this[name].publicInitFunction(item);
    }
}
```